# How to make Custom Serializer from different models?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have 3 different models. I need to build a custom serializer with these 3 models. I tried using some code, but it didn't reach what I expected.
There is structure, but I was not able to get the data I was expecting

**# Serializer**
This my Serializer and ModelOne, ModelTwo, ModelThree these are my models.

```
class ModelOneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelOne
        fields = ['id', 'obj_1', 'obj_2']


class ModelTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelTwo
        fields = ['id', 'obj_1', 'obj_2']


class ModelThreeSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelThree
        fields = ['id', 'obj_1', 'obj_2']



class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    model_1 = ModelOneSerializer(many=True)
    model_2 = ModelTwoSerializer(many=True)
    model_3 = ModelThreeSerializer(many=True)
```

**# View**

```
class CustomView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CustomSerializer(context={'request': request})
        return Response({'response': 'ok', 'result': serializer.data})
```

**# Expected Output**

```
    {
    "response": "ok",
    "result": {
        "model_1": [
        {
        "id":"1",
        "obj_1":"test",
        "obj_2":"test",
        "obj_3":"test"
        },
        {
        "id":"1",
        "obj_1":"test",
        "obj_2":"test",
        "obj_3":"test"
        }
        ],
        "model_2": [
        {
        "id":"1",
        "obj_1":"test",
        "obj_2":"test",
        "obj_3":"test"
        }
        ],
        "model_3": [
        {
        "id":"1",
        "obj_1":"test",
        "obj_2":"test",
        "obj_3":"test"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

The results may have multiple data in the model_2 and model_3 as in the model_1 structure

Comment: Do you just want to list everything in the corresponding models as you mentioned in the expected response?

Comment: @PankajSaini : Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass *what* to serialize for all the model serializers, so `CustomSerializer` doesn't have anything to serialize against.

You can pass the querysets of the models to `CustomSerializer`:

```
class CustomView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):   
        model_one_qset = ModelOne.objects.all()
        model_two_qset = ModelTwo.objects.all()
        model_three_qset = ModelThree.objects.all()

        qsets_map = {
            'model_1': model_one_qset,
            'model_2': model_two_qset,
            'model_3': model_three_qset,
        }

        serializer = CustomSerializer(qsets_map, context={'request': request})

        return Response({'response': 'ok', 'result': serializer.data})
```